# Cherokee causing problems spawning multiple uwsgi instances

Tags: python, django, cherokee, uwsgi

I am running cherokee to serve a django app using uwsgi.  I have been having some strange behavior since upgrading to cherokee 1.2.x.

The setup worked fine prior to cherokee 1.2.x and I haven't changed any of my configuration.

The problem is that now, when uwsgi is not running and I try to load the django app site, I first get a 503 error.  Subsequent requests work fine.  Looking at the logs I see that cherokee is spawning multiple uwsgi instances and this seems to be the problem.

I have posted the cherokee.error log [here](http://pastebin.com/dV8BeKU9)

It appears that cherokee is spawning multiple uwsgi instances:

```
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address.
```

My configs for uwsgi are:

```
<pidfile>/home/my_home/my_project/uwsgi.pid</pidfile>
<vacuum />
<processes>4</processes>
<harakiri>30</harakiri>
<master />
```

Another symptom of the problem is that after the 503 and then subsequent successful start of uwsgi, I don't have a PID file.  This is because the additional instances of uwsgi that get started and then fail delete the PID file when they exit:

```
binding on TCP port: 45611
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address.
bind(): Address already in use [socket.c line 341]
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
```

So overall, the issues are:

- 503 is displayed on first view after uwsgi is started by cherokee
- No PID file is being created (or rather it's being created but immediately being deleted by another exiting uwsgi process)

A google search for `probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address` only matches against the uwsgi source code, so it seems I'm the only one experiencing this.

I experience this same issue on multiple computers with the same setup.

Any ideas?

Versions of software:

- uWSGI 0.9.6.2
- Cherokee 1.2.1
- Django development trunk (between 1.3 rc and 1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a cherokee bug fixed in trunk:

http://svn.cherokee-project.com/listing.php?repname=Cherokee&peg=6382&rev=6380

I downloaded trunk from SVN and I am no longer experiencing the problem.

Comment: This is fixed as of cherokee 1.2.2